# Google Earth API stop support?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-earth

I'm building a web application which integrate Google Earth API to Google Map V3. Here is my approach:

```js
var myOptions = {
  zoom: 4,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(48.25, 11.00),
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), myOptions);
var ge = new GoogleEarth(map);
```

According to the notice from Google, Google Earth API will be stopped supported on December 12th, 2015.

I understand that 'ge' is a wrapped Google Earth API instance. I would like to confirm whether when Google Earth API stops support, the 'ge' instance in my code can continue working or not. And if it can't, is there any solution for building a map like this https://www.google.com/maps/preview/?force=webgl (notice: your browser must support WebGL to view the map)?

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately When API is no longer supported, your 'ge' variable will no longer work.

You can look at this [GitHub](https://github.com/mattcooper/webgl-layer) for the WebGL layer that you can use in your Google Maps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Verma. But webgl-layer of Matt cannot solve my problem. I'm finding a solution to display google map in 3D view like this https://www.google.com/maps/preview/?force=webgl